# Construction of Brownian motion - differentiability

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I'm working on the the construction of BM given by Lévy-Ciesielski. The author begin to prove another result and for this reason he assume that BM exists and that it is also differentiable. For this reason he comes to the point where he write that the derived process on $[0,1]$ is normal since limit of normal random variables. But I don't see why the derivative have to be centered and with $Cov(W_t',W_s')=0 \forall t\neq s$. Moreover he states that  $\mathbb{E}((W_t')^2)=\mathbb{E}\left[\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{W_{t+h}-W_{t}}{h}\right)^2\right]=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{h}{h^2}=\infty$.

So I think that my questions are all related with the problem of interchanging the limit. I don't see why the derivatives have to be centred, have covariance 0 and the reason we can interchange the limit in the above equality.

Comment: He wants to assume (and then prove that this is false) that the BM is differentiable. And so he comes on these results.

Comment: I see now that it may be because the process is assumed to be continuous and hence by using the mean value theorem can we find a bound on the quotient to be able to use dominated convergence?

Comment: Interesting, but I think you would need a uniform bound across the derivatives of almost every path.

Comment: Someone feel free to write this up, but I think you can prove the sequence is uniformly integrable and use Vitali.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If $W_t'$ *was* normal, then it would have in particular a finite variance, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(W_t')^2)<\infty$.

Comment: @saz I agree with you but apparently he is not taking care of it. I use it to making the suggestion that for $t$ fix then $s\mapsto \mathbb{E}(W_s'W_t')$ should be the Dirac function at $t$

Comment: @sky90 I'm not talking about the covariance function. My point is that $W_t'$ cannot be normal (if it does indeed hold true that $\mathbb{E}((W_t')^2)=\infty$).

Comment: @saz I understood what you mean. I just give his motivation to write that. But at this point I'm really confused about the argument

Comment: @sky90 So which book is it? And what does the author really use to get a contradiction?

Comment: it is not a book. I have this from my lecture notes